# Is this a proper Emacs (24.3.2) lisp style to load user .el files from .emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have several .el files within my "~/.emacs.d" directory and I added the following lines to my .emacs file to load them at startup:

```
(let ((base "~/.emacs.d/")
      (files '("user.el" "erlang.el" "sbcl-slime.el"))
      (bfload (lambda (file) (load (expand-file-name (concat base file))))))
   (mapcar bfload files))
```

It works, but is this proper Emacs Lisp style? How can this be improved, please?

Comment: Normally you would add them to the `load-path` and then `require` (this implies that the file you are loading `provide`s something.) Some prefer not to require the files until the corresponding mode would be loaded: [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935908/emacs-best-practice-for-lazy-loading-modes-in-emacs).

Comment: @wvxvw Actually those `*.el` files are just wrappers for _providers_ (only setting up correct pathes for them) and I just didn't want to clutter the `.emacs` file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, don't put your .el files directly into ~/.emacs.d (Emacs puts various files in there, and they're not expected to be Elisp packages).  You can put them into `~/.emacs.d/pkgs` for example, instead.

How 'bout:

```
(dolist (file '("user.el" "erlang.el" "sbcl-slime.el"))
  (load (expand-file-name file "~/.emacs.d/pkgs"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can mix Stefan's excellent suggestions of moving those files to a separate directory with init-loader https://github.com/emacs-jp/init-loader

You will have a couple of extra perks (auto byte-compiling the files) and you won't need to maintain the file list (just move/create a file in that directory).

Comment: The `init-loader` is a very interesting project, but just a bit to bloated to what I had in mind. But thank You for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Stefan's example, I only add a `file-exists-p`:

```
(dolist (file '("user.el" "erlang.el" "sbcl-slime.el"))
  (let ((f (expand-file-name file "~/.emacs.d/pkgs")))
    (if (file-exists-p f)
      (load f))))
```

I think, this is the version I will use.

Comment: `file-exists-p` is a fine idea.  You could also use the `noerror` argument of `load` to get the same result.